# Algorithm to visit 1 node from each group

Tags: algorithm, graph, neo4j, shortest-path, dijkstra

### Example

> A intergalactic space explorer wants to visit one planet from each solar system.
>   The travel time between solar systems is different dependent on what planet you travel from/to due to different technologies. It may be quicker to travel to another planet in the current solar system to catch a transfer. The explorer has to travel to at least one planet from each solar system.

[Here is a graphic example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmmMz.jpg)

In the graphic we will need to visit at least one from each colour, and can begin/end anywhere. Is there an algorithm to complete this? It's similar to Dijkstra but not quite. I currently have my data in Neo4j but am able to change this.

From the graphic example I can see how to navigate the network but the real life example has close to 1000 groupings and each group has at least 8 nodes.

Comment: You can reduce from Traveling Salesman Problem by making every solar system have one planet.  So this is NP-Hard